# Does it make sense to install my Python unit tests in site-packages?

Tags: python, unit-testing, installation, setuptools, software-distribution

I'm developing my first Python distribution package. My learning curve on
Python packaging seems to be leveling off a bit, but I'm still wrestling with
a few open questions. One is whether I should cause my unit tests to be
installed alongside my code.

I understand [it's important to include tests in a source distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436912/what-are-the-use-cases-for-a-python-distribution). What I'm wondering is whether I should actually configure them to be installed?

I've seen at least one popular package that appears to do this on purpose
([PyHamcrest](https://github.com/hamcrest/PyHamcrest)), and at least one other that appears to do it by accident
([behave](https://github.com/jeamland/behave)).

So my (multi-part) question is this:

- Does it ever make sense to install my package unit tests alongside my
  package code?
- If so, what is the use case? Who would use them and for what? That is, who
  would use them that wouldn't be perfectly happy to download the source
  distribution and run `python setup.py test` instead?
- And how would they use installed unit tests? like `import test; test.run()` or something
  like that?

Comment: Off the top of my head, it would be useful to be able to determine that a package works/installed correctly, especially when you are distributing to different platforms and/or have third party dependencies that may or may not differ from version to version.

Comment: Hi Joel, the question I'm asking here is specifically why it might make sense to **install** the tests rather than just include them in the source distribution.

Comment: `numpy` `scipy` `pandas` `sympy` `blaze` `numba` `skimage` all have tests installed in site-packages, for what it's worth

Comment: @endolith Do they name them distinctively (e.g. like 'numpy_tests') or is the one you get when you `import test` a crap-shoot based on install order or something like that?

Comment: @scanny They're like `numpy.linalg.tests`, `numpy.fft.tests`, `scipy.fftpack.tests`, `panda.tests`, `sympy.integrals.tests`, `skimage.segmentation.tests`, `blaze.tests`, `numba.tests`, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After researching this issue, and until someone more experienced has a minute to weigh in to the contrary, my understanding is that the simple answer is: "No, unit tests should not be installed, only included in the *source distribution*".

In the handful of cases I found where tests were installed, all turned out to be **accidental** and it's **easier than one might think to make the mistake** without noticing it.

Here's how it happens:

1. The `packages=find_packages()` parameter is used in setup.py so packages can be found without having to list them out explicitly.
2. The `test` folder is made into a package (by adding `__init__.py`) so tests can reference the modules they test using relative naming (like `from .. import pkg.mod`).
3. `setuptools` installs `test` as a separate package, alongside the other(s) in the project. Note this means you can execute `import test` in the python interpreter and it works, almost certainly not what you intended, especially since a lot of other folks use that name for their test directory :)

The fix is to use the setting: `packages=find_packages(exclude=['test'])` to prevent your test directory from being installed.

Comment: by the way, how do you test your package installation, using the tests from the source distribution? I mean is there a characteristic command line or function call to do this?

Comment: `the handful of cases I found` do you remember which ones?

Answer (score 14):

In my opinion the right answer is NO but you will find quite a few distributions that install the tests. Tests shouldn't be installed but they should be included in the source distribution. In my opinion in an ideal world testing installed packages should be a task performed by the package manager (pip) and the `site-packages` directory shouldn't be polluted with test sources.

I've recently researched this topic and gathered information from various sources and found several different ways to structure the directory/package hierarchy of a distribution that contains both library sources and tests. Most of those structures seem to be obsolete and they were invented as attempts to work around the incomplete feature-sets of older distribution systems at the time. Unfortunately a lot of online sources (older blogposts/documentation) are still advertising the outdated methods so it's very easy to find an outdated distribution how-to/tutorial with online search.

Let's assume you have a library called "my_lib" and you want to structure the sources of your distribution. I will show two popular and seemingly outdated ways to structure your distribution and a third way I've found to be the most versatile. The third method may also be outdated but that's the best one I know a the time of posting this answer. ;-)

## Method #1

Distributions that (intentionally or unintentionally) install tests usually use this method.

**hierarchy**

```
+- my_lib
|  +- __init__.py
|  +- source1.py
|  +- source2.py
|  +- tests
|     +- __init__.py
|     +- test_1.py
|     +- test_2.py
+- setup.py
```

## Method #2

Tests aren't installed but they should be included in the source distribution through the `MANIFEST.in` file.

**hierarchy**

```
+- my_lib
|  +- __init__.py
|  +- source1.py
|  +- source2.py
+- tests
|  +- __init__.py
|  +- test_1.py
|  +- test_2.py
+- setup.py
```

## Method #3 (I prefer this one.)

This is similar to Method #2 with a little twist (the `src` dir).

**hierarchy**

```
+- src
|  +- my_lib
|     +- __init__.py
|     +- source1.py
|     +- source2.py
+- tests
|  +- __init__.py
|  +- test_1.py
|  +- test_2.py
+- setup.py
```

**setup() call in setup.py**

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    ...
)
```

**MANIFEST.in**

```
recursive-include tests *.py
```

Tests won't be installed but they will be included in the source distribution through our `MANIFEST.in`.

In case of method #3 you have an `src` directory that usually contains only a single package that is the root of your lib. Putting the `my_lib` package into an `src` directory (directory and not a package so you don't need an `src/__init__.py`) has the following benefits:

- When you execute `setup.py` the directory that contains `setup.py` is implicitly added to the python path. This means that in your `setup.py` you can accidentally and improperly import stuff from your library if it's package is in the same directory as `setup.py`. By putting the `my_lib` package into `src` we can avoid this problem.
- You can easily use your distributed test sources to test both the distributed library sources and the installed library:

  - When you run the tests with `setup.py test` the `package_dir={'': 'src'}` part of your `setup()` call guarantees that your tests will see your `my_lib` library package that you keep in `src/my_lib`.
  - You can also run tests without `setup.py`. In the simplest case you can do that with the `python -m unittest` command. In this case the `src` dir won't be part of the python path so you can use this method to test the installed version of the library instead of the sources in `src`.

Comment: The pitfalls the method 3 layout avoids are also described in pytest good integration practices: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules
I started following it after falling for those myself.

Answer (score 2):

However I am no expert, I would like to share my opinion.

I would always put tests alongside the code if I expect something might fail depending on the external reasons. Be it bit-order, strange time zones, character coding, 24-bit integers or anything else bizarre you can encounter and have a test for.

Who would not be happy to download the source and run tests?
Maybe some `debian` users that packages are stripped from sources (I know you are talking about python but let me be a little bit general) and your library can occasionally fail due to some strange things in the system.

If your tests ensure internal sanity only, I would skip attaching them, as with out sources they are not worth much, since you will never alter the internals of the library.

Personally, I've heard about a thing failing cause it was moved to some IBM machine which had different bit-ordering. I don't remember if it depended on bit operation or had something pre-computed and cached statically. But it is sometimes wise to check whether you load what you think you saved.

EDIT:
Maybe it will be better to rephrase it. I would install tests when you feel there might be portability caveats. I think it is always good to check things when you deploy stuff on a different system.