# Including unit tests in (test.)pypi package

Tags: python, unit-testing, pip, workflow, pypi

I have a set of unit tests in my package which run nicely during my development workflow, and automatically when I push to github (using `travis`).  Before distributing my project on pypi, I uploaded to the test pypi server (https://test.pypi.org), but I'm unclear on how to test the package at this stage.  I've never seen unit tests included in an official distribution, and I've [seen some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454744/does-it-make-sense-to-install-my-python-unit-tests-in-site-packages) that suggest it shouldn't be done.  **But then, how can one test that the actual packaged version of a code is working properly?**

I did try to include my unit tests in the pypi distribution: in my `MANIFEST.in` I have,

```
include PACKAGE/tests
recursive-include PACKAGE/tests *
```

I've added `include_package_data=True,` in my `setup.py`, and I added a `__main__.py` file with,

```
import nose
nose.main()
```

in it.  When I run the pip-installed package as a module (i.e. `python -m PACKAGE`) it doesn't find any unit tests to run.  **Is this the wrong direction, and is there a better approach?**

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to include the tests in the package in order to test it. You can install the package from pypi, make sure the installed package is found by the python interpreter (not some local working copy of the package), and then run your local copy of the test scripts.

Comment: Downvoted because OP is asking "How can I do X?", and you're simply saying "You don't need to do X. You can do Y." when X and Y are totally different things.

Comment: I don't agree. Although the title may suggest it, the question was not how to include unit tests in a package, but how to ensure that the packaged code works properly, and whether there is a better approach to do so than including the unit tests in the package. Both questions are marked in bold by the original poster.